# flutter array of items showing error in method

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to print the index of array element as another array. I have array list name btns. It contains the value is true or false. I want the index of element having true. here my code is

```
List<bool> btn = [true, false, true, false, false, false, false];
Map<int, bool> map2 = btn.asMap();
var arr = new List<int>();
map2.forEach((key, value) {
  if (value) {
    print(key);
    arr.add(key);
  }
});

print(arr);
```

It is printin [0,2]. And showing correct results. But when I put in method. It showing error.

```
List<int> getbtnsInArray() {
Map<int, bool> map2 = btn.asMap();
var arr = new List<int>();
map2.forEach((key, value) {
  if (value) {
    print(key);
    arr.add(key);
  }
});
   return arr;
}

print (getbtnsInArray);
```

It showing the error is Closure: () => List from Function 'getbtnsInArray':.

I don't know the reason. Please help me to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add brackets to call the method.

```
print(getbtnsInArray());
```